# fread zipped file with 7z

Tags: r, windows, data.table, 7zip

I want to read in a file with `fread` in R. I have `7z` installed.

I tried

```
fread(shell(cmd = '7z l test.txt.gz'), shell = 'cmd.exe'))
```

However I get the error

```
Error in fread(shell(cmd = paste0("7z x ", "\"", dest, "\""), shell = "cmd.exe")) : 
  'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or the input data itself
```

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
 fread(shell(cmd = 'unzip -cq test.zip', shell = 'cmd.exe'))
```

Comment: The error explains, right? `fread('unzip -cq test.zip')` is the syntax, not `fread(shell(cmd = 'unzip -cq test.zip'))`

Comment: do `7z` and `unzip` have the same functionality? the server i am running this on does not have `unzip` (another one does)

Comment: Yeah, I think 7z can handle a txt inside a gz. `fread("7z x -so test.txt.gz")` .. Fwiw, I used fread + 7z for a csv inside a tar.gz and wrote a helper function (requiring magrittr) for that special case: https://github.com/franknarf1/r-tutorial/issues/29

Answer (score 1):

One work-around is to copy `7z.exe` to the project folder. And try:

```
DT = fread(cmd = '7z e -so "test.zip"')
```

Some people suggested adding 7-zip to Windows PATH Environment Variable. But it did not work for me.

Comment: I enclose the entirety of the path to 7zip in the function call, e.g. fread(cmd = '"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7.exe" e -so "test.zip"'
Note that for some reason it only works with the quotes this way around - single quote outside, double quote inside.